# Migrating Wordpress users into Disqus

Tags: users, disqus

I'm thinking of migrating my comment system from Wordpress to Disqus. I'm pretty satisfied with options it offers, but I have one problem:

I have few hundred registrated users on my Wordpress instalation, those accounts were used for commenting. Can I import my Wordpress users so they don't have to go through registration once again? But still retain Disqus login options for those who have account there?

edit:
So, basically, can user just log into his WP account and post on Disqus comment system?

Answer (score 2):

### Update

If you're running a big site, you may be able to take advantage of the [Disqus Single Sign-On System](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/sso/)!

### Original Post

**No** but...

WordPress comments can be imported into Disqus using WordPress' WXR export format! Disqus has a [doc on WXR importing](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/export/import_format/). The WXR format includes the users' email addresses, which is fantastic because according to [this Disqus document about merging accounts](http://docs.disqus.com/help/40/):

> Guest comments posted with your email address can be claimed at Edit Profile > Merging. This option only appears once you've verified your email address.

So users can *reclaim* their comments by

1. Signing up for a Disqus account.
2. Verifying their email address.
3. Merging their accounts.

If you allow guest comments, users' comments *may be linked* if they provide their email address along with their comment. I'm uncertain about how Disqus displays guest comments, however.

Disqus has a separate user table than your blog. Unfortunately that means that your users can't sign into your blog and immediately comment into Disqus. It's trivial to sign up for a Disqus account though, as you probably know, so I wouldn't let that dissuade you.